# Problems with namespacing

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have the following problem. I am trying to wrap a code from C++ to java.

common.h

```
namespace rinad {
namespace mad_manager {

template<class T>
class Encoder{
public:
    virtual ~Encoder(){}
    virtual void encode(const T &obj, ser_obj_t& serobj) = 0;
    virtual void decode(const ser_obj_t &serobj,
        T& des_obj) = 0;
};
typedef struct ipcp_config{
....
}ipcp_config_t;
}}
```

encoders.h

```
namespace rinad {
namespace mad_manager {
class IPCPConfigEncoder: public Encoder<ipcp_config_t> {
public:
    void encode (const ipcp_config_t &obj,
                ser_obj_t& ser_obj);
    void decode(const ser_obj_t &ser_obj,
        ipcp_config_t& obj);
    std::string get_type() const{ return "ipcp-config"; };
};
}}
```

librinad.i

```
%{
#include "common.h"
#include "encoders.h"
%}
%include "common.h"

%template(TempIPCPConfigEncoder) rinad::mad_manager::Encoder<rinad::mad_manager::ipcp_config_t>;

%include "encoders.h"
```

The generated .cc file (`swig <options> -o librinad_java.cc`) however does not consider some namespaces which results in an error.

librinad_java.cc:836:32: error: 'ipcp_config_t' was not declared in this scope
   rinad::mad_manager::Encoder< ipcp_config_t > *arg1 = (rinad::mad_manager::Encoder< ipcp_config_t > *) 0 ;

I have tried to specify every namespace (even if it is not necessary) but it doesn't work neither. If I manually add the namespace `rinad::mad_manager::ipcp_config_t` in `librinad_java.cc` it works, so the problem is that SWIG does not export this namespace. I can not figure out which is the problem here.

Side question. I have had to split the code shown in `common.h` from the one shown in `encoders.h` to be able to specify in the `.i` the template before it is instantiated (`encoders.h`) but after `ipcp_config_t` has been defined (`common.h`). Is this the only way to do that?

Comment: If instead of ipcp_config_t I use ipcp_config it works! I do not know why... I suppose it is a typedef wrapping problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is an answer. Do not do

```
typedef struct ipcp_config{
....
}ipcp_config_t;
```

but

```
typedef struct{
....
}ipcp_config_t;
```

this worked for me because I do not need the forwarding declaration. I still don't know what to do if the declaration is neeeded (for example in recursive structures)